# Vendor table in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So I have a database consisting of different PC components, a customer table and a sales tables. I'm trying to work out how to impliment it so, when I add a vendor table, a different price can be selected for the sale items based on the cheapest price available

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`customer` (
  `customer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_first_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_last_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`))


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`sale` (
  `sale_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `sale_items` INT(3) NOT NULL,
  `sale_paid` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_customer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sale_id`, `customer_customer_id`),
  INDEX `fk_sale_customer1_idx` (`customer_customer_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sale_customer1`
FOREIGN KEY (`customer_customer_id`)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`customer` (`customer_id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I'm guessing I need a `vendor_id` and `vendor_name` for the vendor table, but where would I put the vendors price for each of the 6 component tables I have `cpu`, `psu` etc etc, and how would I make it so it when a sale is made, it pulls from the cheapest vendor, and display which one it is?

I'm a bit of a novice here, so that's why I'm asking for so much help

Answer (score 1):

Having 6 separate tables for what is essentially the same information about different entities is, I think, a major contributor to your problem.

Many years ago I worked on a system to record sample data from an industrial process, and I think the underlying principle is the same. There is no need for ***the program logic*** to distinguish between the characteristics of one type of component and those of another type, or between different characteristics of the same type, so you can abstract the entire set of component tables into a single "specification" entity.

The classic solution to this problem would be to have something like the following:

```
components (
  component_id primary key
  type references component_types
  description
  etc.)

vendors (
  vendor_id primary key,
  name
  address
  etc.)

vendor_catalog (
  vendor_id references vendors
  component_id references components
  vendor_catalog_no
  price
  etc.
  pk(vendor_id, component_id))

characteristics (
  specification_id primary key
  spec_name
  type references component_types
  description
  units
  lower_limit
  upper_limit
  etc.

specifications (
  specification_id references characteristics
  component_id references components
  vendor_id references vendors
  value
  pk(component_id, vendor_id, specification_id)
  index(component_id, specification_id) not unique
```

The above is necessarily incomplete; I leave it to you to fill in datatypes, other fields, &c. as well as the `component_types` lookup table.

There would be equally-valid alternate choices for some of the foreign keys, and the extra non-unique index on `specifications` is an early optimization which might prove unnecessary. Also. the whole schema is something I whipped up on the spur of the moment and should in no way be taken as gospel.

Comment: Sorry, I have 6 tables with different PC components in :) Thanks for this answer

Comment: May I ask why you have 6?

Comment: `storage` `powersupply` `memory` `motherboard` `cpu` `graphicscard` `case` I have 7, my bad

Comment: So why do you have separate tables for them, instead of one with a `component_type` column to distinguish them? Are you trying to keep track of different characteristics for each type? Even then it would simplify your life immeasurably to have a single `components` table as their parent, and I can think of several other improvements as well.

Comment: I would love to hear them :) They have a fair few different properties for each to be honest, but it is possible

Comment: I've expanded my answer above to show one approach I have used professionally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97790/discussion-between-badja-and-darwin-von-corax).